# Removing Duplicate Values in MultiCombobox

Tags: javascript, json, xml, sap-fiori

Hi guys I am trying to learn JSON Binding in Fiori. I want to remove Duplicate values in this MultiCombobox.

MY XML section is here

```
<fb:FilterItem name="Side" label="Side">
                <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox selectionChange="handleSelectionChange" selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish" width="" placeholder="Choose Side." required="true" items="{Wolfteam>/Characters}" mergeDuplicates ="true">
                    <core:Item key="{Wolfteam>Side}" text="{Wolfteam>Side}" />

                
                    </MultiComboBox>
                    
                </fb:control>
            </fb:FilterItem>
```

My JSON is here

```
{ 
    "Characters": [{
            "Name": "Pedro Gomez",
            "Health": "200",
            "Side": "Red"
            
        },
        {
            "Name": "Angela Mao",
            "Health": "210",
            "Side": "Blue"
            
        },
        {
            "Name": "Adriana Tenorio",
            "Health": "230",
            "Side": "Red"
            
        },
        {
            "Name": "Pedro Gomez",
            "Health": "240",
            "Side": "Blue"
            
        }

    ]

}
```

I tried Chat GPT and Sap Forums.  Didnt find any solutions

Comment: <fb:FilterItem name="Side" label="Side">
                <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox selectionChange="handleSelectionChange" selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish" width="" placeholder="Choose Side." required="true" items="{Wolfteam>/Characters}" mergeDuplicates ="true">
                    <core:Item key="{Wolfteam>Side}" text="{Wolfteam>Side}" />

                
                    </MultiComboBox>
                    
                </fb:control>
            </fb:FilterItem>

Comment: Code does no help in a comment; [edit] the question instead.